# Magento 2: Bug or developer mode issue

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.1.6

I am facing the issue with  **Magento ver. 2.1.6**. When I am login still showing me log in when I click on cart checkout button.

Refresh the browser solved the problem.

[image]

Did anyone face the smiler issue?

Comment: Yes faced same issue. Some times. I hope mostly dealing with Session/Cookie data load

Comment: I was facing same issue, Once i remove the var/cache/ and /generation, everything works fine in developer mode.

Comment: @Krishati95Dev after refresh the browser it works for me but why it's happened?

Comment: Please check with enable all cache and check issue again.  i have same issue arise and solved using above tricks.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya cache enable solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the common issue of magento 2.

You can check its in github link,

[1. Logged-in user has to re-login before checkout.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7554)

[2. Login Popup appears while clicking "Proceed to checkout" even after logged in](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4589)

```
You can resolved issue by below tricks,
```

**Please enable all cache from admin for developer mode.**

Clear Var folder and clear cache.